# How to disable microphone (Receive-only) access while connect to WebRTC class iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, screensharing

We are trying to disable the `microphone` access for `WebRTCClient` class to use `Receive-only` Video & Audio for the display `ReplayKit` render Remote Video & Audio.

The ReplayKit renders Remote Video Integrate with WebRTC iOS Swift class:

```
class WebRTCClient: NSObject {
    
    // The `RTCPeerConnectionFactory` is in charge of creating new RTCPeerConnection instances.
    // A new RTCPeerConnection should be created for every new call, but the factory is shared.
    private static let factory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory = {
        RTCInitializeSSL()
        let videoEncoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory()
        let videoDecoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory()
        return RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: videoEncoderFactory, decoderFactory: videoDecoderFactory)
    }()
    
    private let peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection
    private let rtcAudioSession =  RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    private let mediaConstrains = [kRTCMediaConstraintsOfferToReceiveAudio: kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue,
                                   kRTCMediaConstraintsOfferToReceiveVideo: kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue]
    
    private var videoCapturer: RTCVideoCapturer?
    private var localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
    private var remoteVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
    private var remoteDataChannel: RTCDataChannel?
    private var remoteAudioTrack: RTCAudioTrack?
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    override init() {
        fatalError("WebRTCClient:init is unavailable")
    }
    
    required init(iceServers: [String]) {
        let config = RTCConfiguration()
        config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers)]
        
        // Unified plan is more superior than planB
        config.sdpSemantics = .unifiedPlan
        
        // gatherContinually will let WebRTC to listen to any network changes and send any new candidates to the other client
        config.continualGatheringPolicy = .gatherContinually
        
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil,
                                              optionalConstraints: ["DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement":kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue,
                                                                    kRTCMediaConstraintsOfferToReceiveAudio: kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue,
                                                                    kRTCMediaConstraintsOfferToReceiveVideo: kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue])
        
        self.peerConnection = WebRTCClient.factory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: constraints, delegate: nil)
        super.init()
        self.createMediaSenders()
        self.configureAudioSession()
        self.peerConnection.delegate = self
    }
    
    func classSetup() { }
    
    // MARK: Signaling
    func offer(completion: @escaping (_ sdp: RTCSessionDescription) -> Void) {
        let constrains = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: self.mediaConstrains,
                                             optionalConstraints: nil)
        self.peerConnection.offer(for: constrains) { (sdp, error) in
            guard let sdp = sdp else {
                return
            }
            self.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp, completionHandler: { (error) in
                completion(sdp)
            })
        }
    }
    
    func answer(completion: @escaping (_ sdp: RTCSessionDescription) -> Void)  {
        let constrains = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: self.mediaConstrains,
                                             optionalConstraints: nil)
        self.peerConnection.answer(for: constrains) { (sdp, error) in
            guard let sdp = sdp else {
                return
            }
            self.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp, completionHandler: { (error) in
                completion(sdp)
            })
        }
    }
    
    func set(remoteSdp: RTCSessionDescription, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        self.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteSdp, completionHandler: completion)
    }
    
    func set(remoteCandidate: RTCIceCandidate) {
        self.peerConnection.add(remoteCandidate)
    }
    
    // MARK: Media
    func startCaptureLocalVideo(renderer: RTCVideoRenderer, isFrontCamera: Bool) {
        guard let capturer = self.videoCapturer as? RTCCameraVideoCapturer else {
            return
        }
        guard
            let frontCamera = (RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices().first { $0.position == .front }),
                // choose highest res
            let format = (RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: frontCamera).sorted { (f1, f2) -> Bool in
                let width1 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f1.formatDescription).width
                let width2 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f2.formatDescription).width
                return width1 < width2
            }).last,
                // choose highest fps
            let fps = (format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.sorted { return $0.maxFrameRate < $1.maxFrameRate }.last) else {
            return
        }
        capturer.startCapture(with: frontCamera,
                              format: format,
                              fps: Int(fps.maxFrameRate))
        self.localVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
    }
    
    func renderRemoteVideo(to renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {
        self.remoteVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
    }
    
    func removeRenderRemoteVideo(to renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {
        self.remoteVideoTrack?.remove(renderer)
    }
    
    private func configureAudioSession() {
        self.rtcAudioSession.lockForConfiguration()
        do {
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint("Error changeing AVAudioSession category: \(error)")
        }
        self.rtcAudioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
    
    func createMediaSenders() {
        let streamId = "XYZ"
        self.rtcAudioSession.useManualAudio = true
        self.rtcAudioSession.isAudioEnabled = false
        // Audio
        let audioTrack = self.createAudioTrack()
        self.peerConnection.add(audioTrack, streamIds: [streamId])
        self.remoteAudioTrack = self.peerConnection.transceivers.first { $0.mediaType == .audio }?.receiver.track as? RTCAudioTrack
    }


    private func createAudioTrack() -> RTCAudioTrack {
        let audioConstrains = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: mediaConstrains, optionalConstraints: nil)
        let audioSource = WebRTCClient.factory.audioSource(with: audioConstrains)
        let audioTrack = WebRTCClient.factory.audioTrack(with: audioSource, trackId: "ARDAMSa0")
        return audioTrack
    }
    
    private func createVideoTrack() -> RTCVideoTrack {
        let videoSource = WebRTCClient.factory.videoSource()
        #if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
        self.videoCapturer = RTCFileVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)
        #else
        self.videoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)
        #endif
        let videoTrack = WebRTCClient.factory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: "ARDAMSv0")
        return videoTrack
    }
    
    // MARK: Data Channels
    private func createDataChannel() -> RTCDataChannel? {
        let config = RTCDataChannelConfiguration()
        guard let dataChannel = self.peerConnection.dataChannel(forLabel: "WebRTCData", configuration: config) else {
            debugPrint("Warning: Couldn't create data channel.")
            return nil
        }
        return dataChannel
    }
    
    func sendData(_ data: Data) {
        let buffer = RTCDataBuffer(data: data, isBinary: true)
        self.remoteDataChannel?.sendData(buffer)
    }
}
```

This class always accesses `microphone` enabled by default when the socket is connected successfully.

We are trying to follow the code for disabling the `microphone` when `creating Media Senders`:

```
self.rtcAudioSession.isAudioEnabled = false
```

but, isn't any success to disable `microphone` access.

please give a solution for a `receive-only` `WebRTCClient` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your initializator

```swift
let webRTCConfiguration = RTCAudioSessionConfiguration.init()
webRTCConfiguration.mode = AVAudioSession.Mode.moviePlayback.rawValue
webRTCConfiguration.category = AVAudioSession.Category.playback.rawValue
webRTCConfiguration.categoryOptions = AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.duckOthers

RTCAudioSessionConfiguration.setWebRTC(webRTCConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

to disable microphone add this:   self.audioTrack?.isEnabled = true